# PostgreSQL jsonb as hash tables/dictionaries?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb

PostgreSQL does not seem to have a native data type for dictionaries. The new `jsonb` (and `json`) type seems to have the right interface: given a key, a jsonb object returns a value.

I am just wondering about the performance (computational complexity) of using `jsonb` or `hstore` as dictionaries. (I read that the `json` type is inefficient.) My question is:

*Does the jsonb type have the same computational complexities as dictionaries? (e.g. logarithmic time for looking up a value, etc.)*

If jsonb is not suitable, what's the idiomatic way to implement/use dictionaries (e.g. in PL/pgsql)

(this is with PostgreSQL 14+)

Related:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150617

Comment: Why do you care how it's implemented? You will have to do some benchmarking anyway using _your_ data and _your_ access patterns in order to find out if it performs to your expectations. PL/pgSQL isn't intended for mass data manipulation to begin with. If you need to search/update large amounts of data then SQL is a better approach. If all you do is manipulate JSON data (key/value "documents"), then maybe a different database technology is a better choice anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `Why do you care how it's implemented?`.  What I care isn't really how it's implemented per se. It's more about whether SQL supports data types such as dictionaries. The jsonb/hstore types have an interface of a dictionary (so it seems). Hence the question whether the computational complexity match. It's really about the specification.

Comment: More specifically about plpgsql, I am interested because other PL languages such as  PL/python and PL/lua might be more appropriate for implementing certain functions if PL/pgsql doesn't have dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

JSON in PostgreSQL isn't inefficient per se; it depends on what you do with it and what your expectations are.

Looking up a value by key will be an efficient operation with type `jsonb`. But much of that efficiency might be lost if you have a large dictionary, because the whole JSON gets read from disk and loaded into memory.

You may be better off storing each key-value pair in a single table row, but you should benchmark both solutions.